# Android to php. Error parsing data org.json string cannot convert to jSon

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I searched for many solution but stil don't work. 
I still getting the error of converting string to `JSONObject`
Here is my code:

```
 public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is,"iso-8859-1",8));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", json);
            //Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

This is the string that i wanted to parse:

```
{"products":[{"pid":"1","name":"abc","price":"222.00","created_at":"2013-04-02 12:44:26","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}],"success":1}
```

I learned this [code from here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/).

Also the `jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(3));` dont work for me.

I SOLVED THE PROBLEM:
The problem is on my string which i actually echo some comment in my php and it included in my json string. So i remove my echo from my php and everything wen smoothly. THANKS!

Comment: use `Log.e("JSON Response", "JSon String :- " + json);` and check log  you are getting valid json string from server from server in response

Comment: your json is not vaild.

Answer (score 0):

Your `JSON` is invalid. You are missing one left bracket `[` that indicates `JSONArray` It should be:

```
    {
        "products": [
          {
          "pid":"1",
          "name":"abc",
          "price":"222.00",
          "created_at":"2013-04-02 12:44:26",
          "updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
          }
        ],
        "success":1
    }
```

### Update:

Your problem is this:

```
if (method == "POST") { .. } // and same for GET
```

This always return **false** because you are trying to compare strings with **`==`** operator that compares references. You have to use `equals()` method because you want to compare values of strings.

Comment: @max it's strange. Try to remove encoding from `BufferedReader`.

Comment: removed and it's still the same. I edited my post above and posted my entire method maybe you could spot any problem there? I am still new to this

Comment: i tried using method.equals.("GET") but still din't work. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to validate your json. You can use http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: i have validated it and it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.aam1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;

    static JSONArray jarr = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public  JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                if(httpEntity == null)
                {      String msg = "No response from server";   
                return null;
                }            
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString().trim();
            Log.i("StringBuilder...", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {

            jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(3));
            jarr = new JSONArray(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
           // Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data [" + e.getMessage()+"] "+json);

            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
            } catch (Exception e0) {

                Log.e("JSON Parser0", "Error parsing data0 [" + e0.getMessage()+"] "+json);
                Log.e("JSON Parser0", "Error parsing data0 " + e0.toString());

                try {
                    jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(1));
                } catch (Exception e1) {

                    Log.e("JSON Parser1", "Error parsing data1 [" + e1.getMessage()+"] "+json);
                    Log.e("JSON Parser1", "Error parsing data1 " + e1.toString());

                    try {
                        jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(2));
                    } catch (Exception e2) {

                        Log.e("JSON Parser2", "Error parsing data2 [" + e2.getMessage()+"] "+json);
                        Log.e("JSON Parser2", "Error parsing data2 " + e2.toString());

                        try {
                            jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(3));
                        } catch (Exception e3) {

                            Log.e("JSON Parser3", "Error parsing data3 [" + e3.getMessage()+"] "+json);
                            Log.e("JSON Parser3", "Error parsing data3 " + e3.toString());

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
 //       return new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));

    }
}
```